# Micromax Canvas A1 is unable to install apps from Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, installation

I have a **Micromax Canvas A1** device. I can open Play Store and can search the apps. But, when I click `Install`, it just shows (endless) download animation and no actual downloading happens.

An example:

[image]

Process is stuck in installation phase and no further progress nor even any notification hapens.

I've tried so far:

1. Clearing Google Play Store data and cache.
2. Doing factory reset of the device.

Still nothing. Anything else, I can try?

Comment: Have you tried using other network connection? Perhaps there is an issue with the connection, or firewall? How about downloading the app from the Play Store website?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache and the data stored by the Google PlayStore App ?? If not then I would advise you to try clearing the cache and the data, and restart your device. Upon restarting open the Google PlayStore and check if you can everything starts working fine for you. I am pretty much sure that will do the trick for you.

Comment: @PeterCarlos - Thanks for the advice, but as I've mentioned, I've already tried clearing cache, data and uninstalling update. After rebooting, having the same issue.

Comment: @Pankaj Oops my bad I haven't seen bottom of your post. I guess the problem is somewhere with the network only,Okay do one thing stop the download and ask your friend to tether for you connect with it and again try downloading the app and check if that works for you ?

Comment: @PeterCarlos - Well, now I can install using my 3G connection, but not with WiFi and Tethering. Is it a WiFi problem specific for playstore?

Comment: @Pankaj That's great at least now you are able to download apps over the 3G network. But at the same time I am sorry but I don't have anything to comment over here as it has started working back over the 3G network mysteriously, but what I can bet on is the problem is with the network not the PlayStore. Maybe you should try connecting your device with some other Wi-Fi network to check the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup your phone. Do a hard data reset (note, that this is different from a factory reset):

1. Press <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power Button</kbd> all at once.
2. Press <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>.
3. Go to recovery and then select wipe data/factory reset.

If you are facing any troubles, then [this link](http://www.micromax.org/hard-reset-micromax-canvas-hd-a116) should be helpful for you.